# Tensor: what is it and how is it different from a vector?

Tags: machine-learning, math, terminology, tensor

I am beginner in machine learning and I am facing this question please provide me the simple example or content so that I can understand in best way.

Comment: I am 100% this is not the right place for you, try [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/). But first I strongly recommend using google. I found [it](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-vector-and-tensor) in less than 10 seconds :

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming related question.

Comment: @andand , I asked question because I face the problem and if you can't answer then you must skip this question instead of giving down-vote and thanks to **dylan_fan** , he got the problem and suggested me good place for these types of question.

Comment: @sonuchauhan.  I didn't down vote this question; I voted to have it closed as off topic.  A description of questions which are suitable for this site is located at http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about the mathematical objects, then a tensor is something that holds values, some kind of table or array. A tensor has an order indicating on how many axis these values are arranged.

For example:

- A tensor of order 0 is simply a single scalar number.
- A tensor of order 1 is a vector. Each element is numbered by one index.
- A tensor of order 2 is a matrix. Each element has two indices, e.g. row and column.

Answer (score 0):

#### Tensor = multi-dimensional array

In the machine learning literature, a *tensor* is simply a synonym for *multi-dimensional array*:

> Tensors, also known as multidimensional arrays, are generalizations of matrices to higher orders and are useful data representation architectures.

- [Tensors in Statistics](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev-statistics-042720-020816) *Annual Review of Statistics and Its Application* (2021)

Hence a 1.d tensor is a "vector/tuple", and a 2.d. tensor is a "matrix/2.d.array".

#### Implementations

In specific libraries the term may be restricted to numerical arrays:

> [Theano](https://pypi.org/project/Theano/) is a Python library that allows you to define, optimize, and efficiently evaluate mathematical expressions involving multi-dimensional arrays.

or those containing a broader range of data-types:

> [**Tensor**](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/glossary) - The primary data structure in TensorFlow programs. Tensors are N-dimensional (where N could be very large) data structures, most commonly scalars, vectors, or matrices. The elements of a Tensor can hold integer, floating-point, or string values.

#### **Etymology**

Tensor has a [more specific](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/517908/200523) meaning in mathematics as an abstraction of a multilinear map between vector spaces, but given a fixed basis such maps can be *represented as* multidimensional arrays, and it is from this usage that the machine learning term gets its name.